# Using a function's argument in an object - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use type instead of 'data' in the following example, to keep it dynamic, but I have no idea how to do so, could anyone possibly advice on what to do in this case?

Thank you!

I have:

```
    alreadyHas: function(type) {
        return this.dropdownPlan.data.id === this.currentPlan.data.id
    },
```

I want:

```
    alreadyHas: function(type) {
        return this.dropdownPlan.type.id === this.currentPlan.type.id
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `[]` [`Bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) in order to access the field dynamically :

```
  alreadyHas: function(type) {
        return this.dropdownPlan[type].id === this.currentPlan[type].id
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  row: {
    col: {
      row1: {
        title: "Done",
      },
    },
  },
};

let type = "col";
console.log(obj.row[type].row1.title);
```